# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable - Lists and arrays

Tags: list, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to get a list of values for Szeta. Szeta depends on two variables, the first being mean period (tz), the other wave frequency (omega). For each mean period, there will be a list of Szetas for several wave frequencies. Hence I am using numpy to have a Szeta array[j,i]
The code below is what I am trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import os, os.path, sys
import glob
import math
import time 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

omega = np.arange(0.01,3.1,.01)
tz = [4, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]
tP = []
A = [] # combined A - this is the exponential factor that gamma is to the power of
Hs = 1       #SIGNIFICANT WAVE HEIGHT change this for other
gamma = 3.3    #elongation parameter set at 3.3 for Jonswap wave spectrum
A_gamma = 1 - (0.287*math.log(gamma))
omega_p =[]

Szeta = np.zeros((len(tz), len(omega)))

for j in range(0, len(tz)):
    omega_p = (np.pi*2)/(tz[j]*1.285)

    for i in range(0, len(omega)):
        if omega[i] <= omega_p:
            sigma = 0.7
            A = np.exp(-((omega[i]-omega_p)**2)/(2*omega_p**2*sigma**2))
        
        
        elif omega[i] > omega_p:
            sigma = 0.9
            A = np.exp(-((omega[i]-omega_p)**2)/(2*omega_p**2*sigma**2))
                
        Szeta[j,i] = A_gamma*(5/16)*(Hs**2)*(omega_p[j]**4)*(omega[i]**(-5))*np.exp((-5/4)* (omega[i]/omega[j])**(-4))*(gamma**A)
```

Comment: You don't need to share all these information: isolate the problem and create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: if this condition `omega[i] <= omega_p` is false, you there is no need to check for this `omega[i] > omega_p` in the else statement

Comment: the error i get is at the end on Szeta[j, i] = xxxxx

Comment: That's because `omega_p` is a float (1.2224095928364955), not an array. Whay did you except to have? The problem is probably in this line, I suppose `omega_p = (np.pi * 2) / (tz[j] * 1.285)`

Comment: I want the for loop to run for every value of j (aka omega_p solved from tz), i will have a list of answers i (AKA Szeta)